# Creating a batch file with the "IF" command

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file, command

I have created a little batch file for helping people to convert MP4 video to FLV with FFMPEG. A way to make it simple to everyone i know to use it. I was thinking the line i've put in was perfect for every situation (converting a MP4 file to FLV), but few days ago, it didn't work for a file. (audio sample to high for FLV format)

I found with the help of people a other codeline to convert it, but i don't know how to correctly integrate it, in my batch file.

There is what i use right now :

> echo "Enter the name of the file, whitout the extension" : set
>   /p namefile=
>
> echo "Enter the name you what to give to the destination file" : set /p destinationfile=
>
> ffmpeg -i %namefile%.mp4 -c:v libx264 -crf 19 %destinationfile%.flv

And i want to add a "IF". Because if that doesn't work with this line, use that one :

> ffmpeg -i %namefile%.mp4 -c:v libx264 -ar 22050 -crf 28
>   %destinationfile%.flv

How can i do that ?

Thank you very much for your help and if i'm unclear on something, just tell it to me and i will do my best to make it clear.

Thanks !

Comment: Can you write in simple words the condition that you want to test in the `if` statement?

Comment: Hi and thanks @EitanT for this quick answer ! I'm not totally sure of your question, so if i'm wrong, just tell it to me ! The condition i'm looking for, is 
`If FFMPEG cannot convert the video, use this other codeline".`

Or if we talk about the problem the last video get, it's more 
`If the audio sample is not 11025,22050 or 44100, use that codeline`

I hope i correctly answer your question !

Thanks !!

Comment: I've posted an answer. Try it...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure if FFMPEG returns a standard error code in case of failure, but if it does, you can use the following:

```
ffmpeg -i %namefile%.mp4 -c:v libx264 -crf 19 %destinationfile%.flv
if not errorlevel 1 goto Done
ffmpeg -i %namefile%.mp4 -c:v libx264 -ar 22050 -crf 28 %destinationfile%.flv
:Done
```

If this approach doesn't work, you can check the existence of the destination file to determine further action:

```
ffmpeg -i %namefile%.mp4 -c:v libx264 -crf 19 %destinationfile%.flv
if exist %destinationfile%.flv goto Done
ffmpeg -i %namefile%.mp4 -c:v libx264 -ar 22050 -crf 28 %destinationfile%.flv
:Done
```

Hope one of these works.

Comment: Your error logic is inverted in your first script. It should read `if not errorlevel 1 goto Done`

Answer (score 5):

Similar to EitanT's first solution, but without using GOTO.

```
ffmpeg -i %namefile%.mp4 -c:v libx264 -crf 19 %destinationfile%.flv
if errorlevel 1 ffmpeg -i %namefile%.mp4 -c:v libx264 -ar 22050 -crf 28 %destinationfile%.flv
```

or
 ***Edited*** - *the code had gotten truncated, all fixed now*

```
ffmpeg -i %namefile%.mp4 -c:v libx264 -crf 19 %destinationfile%.flv||ffmpeg -i %namefile%.mp4 -c:v libx264 -ar 22050 -crf 28 %destinationfile%.flv
```

Similar to EitanT's second solution, but without using GOTO

```
ffmpeg -i %namefile%.mp4 -c:v libx264 -crf 19 %destinationfile%.flv
if not exist %destinationfile%.flv ffmpeg -i %namefile%.mp4 -c:v libx264 -ar 22050 -crf 28 %destinationfile%.flv
```

Comment: @EitanT - Nothing is technically wrong with a GOTO. But GOTO is slow in batch, and the code without the GOTO is simpler and smaller. The speed difference is insignificant in this case, but I like to minimize the amount of code as long as the logic remains clear.

Comment: I don't think performance is an issue when batch is involved... Also, I see `goto Done` as an equivalent of `return` in C, so to me it actually seems clearer. But I guess it's a matter if style.

Comment: @EitanT - I agree, there is definitely a matter of style, and I agree in this case that performance is not an issue. But there are many cases within loops where GOTO or CALL can kill performance compared to a solution without it. But don't sweat it. I don't have a problem with your answer. I am just providing a more concise alternative. BTW - I do not agree that `goto Done` is like `return` in C. `goto Done` in batch is like `goto Done` in C. `exit /b` in batch is similar to `return` in C.

Comment: Thank you very much to both of you ! If i was enough reputation point i will have put +1 to both of you becauses theses answers are very very usefull to me, thanks !!

I have made several try and they all work (except maybe the code `ffmpeg -i %namefile%.mp4 -c:v libx264 -crf 19 %destinationfile%.flv
if not exist %destinationfile%.flv ffmpeg -i %namefile%.mp4 -c:v libx264 -ar 22050 -crf 28 %destinationfile%.flv` but it's maybe me. For a normal MP4 who use the first line of code for FFMPEG it's working but for a video who need the second, the CMD window close itself)

Thanks again !! :D

Comment: @John_D - the 2nd variation using `!!` had truncated code. All fixed now

Comment: Quick question... for my own information, because `errorlevel` has always been a problem for me. Could you expect `errorlevel` to always be 1? Would it be better to do a `if errorlevel neq 0`?

Comment: @dbenham Thanks a lot ! I test it and that work perfectly !!

Good question iesou, i'm now asking myself about it too.

Comment: @iesou/John_D, the `if errorlevel x` statement actually checks if the errorlevel is _greater or equal_ to x. It's not intuitive, but that's the way it works.